# Declension of "Kinder" in "nicht nur für, sondern auch von Kinder(n)"

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, dative, declension, ellipsis

Ich suche nach der korrekten Deklination des Nomens "Kinder" in diesem Satz:

> Es stellte sich heraus, dass die Spielzeuge nicht nur für, sondern auch von Kinder(n) produziert werden.

Oder ist das ein Fall, der einfach nicht korrekt sein kann und umgangen werden muss. Das wäre nice!

Comment: `sondern auch von Kindern` ist korrekt.

Comment: Also einfach immer an das Letzte anpassen?

Comment: @c.p.mMn eher _ihnen_ als _denen_

Comment: M.E. noch besser: von solchen. Nämlich nicht denselben.

Comment: Das ist eine meiner Lieblingsfragen. Leider ist es mir aber überhaupt nicht klar, ob der Satz im OP besser als etwa *Es stellte sich heraus, dass die Spielzeuge nicht nur für, sondern auch von solchen produziert werden.* ist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Du kannst schreiben:

> Es stellte sich heraus, dass die Spielzeuge nicht nur für, sondern auch von Kindern produziert werden.

Erklärt wird das zum Beispiel bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Wegfall.html#Anchor-Wortgruppenkerne):

> Wenn zwei Attribute oder Begleiter sich auf das gleiche Nomen beziehen, muss das Nomen nur einmal genannt werden. ... Ein Nomen kann auch weggelassen werden, wenn es nicht zweimal im gleichen Kasus oder Numerus steht.

Sie gehen zwar nicht ausdrücklich auf die Frage ein, welcher der beiden Kasus dann "gewinnt", aber aus den Beispielen geht hervor, dass offenbar das letzte Auftreten des Nomens bestimmend ist.

Comment: 'welcher der beiden Kasus dann "gewinnt"' - keiner: Jedes der zwei Auftreten des Nomens wird entsprechend seiner Funktion dekliniert. Der Kürze wegen wird eines der Auftreten dann weggelassen, aber das bedeutet nicht, dass dadurch die zwei Auftreten irgendwie "zusammenfallen" würden und man sich für einen Kasus entscheiden könnte oder müsste.